# In the website login, Chrome found the password you just used in a data breach

Tags: google-chrome, security, passwords

I am getting a popup message when I'm login into my website that "Chrome found the password you just used in a data breach to secure your accounts....".
Is there a way to hide or disable this popup?

[image]

Answer (score 18):

You can Disable this Alert Message in this way...

1. Launch the ***Chrome*** browser on your machine.
2. Click on the vertical 3-dots icon situated at the top right and select the
   ***Settings menu***.
3. Switch to the ***Privacy and Security*** tab, and click on Security.
4. ***Disable the Warn*** you if passwords are exposed in a data breach toggle
   to stop the alert.

Comment: It's a bummer you can't whitelist a specific site. I get this error on a local development domain. Which uses this simple password because it's a local development that resets each time I boot up docker

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessarily the answer you were looking for, but I recommend actually changing your passwords! That would make the popup go away too if it sweetens the pot any.

Comment: It's convenient to use easy to type passwords, which tend to be weak, with local development environments created for ad hoc testing and exploration.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, in Chrome Version 122.0.6261.69, this setting has been moved to `Settings -> Privacy and security -> Safe browsing,` where you need to select `Standard protection,` which allows you to untick `Warn you if passwords are exposed in a data breach.`

It's a real shame that I need to use admin:admin credentials for a lot of local testing, and I need to lower the overall protection rules to skip warning messages popping up all over the place. Come on, Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with others, that being able to whitelist certain local domains or to whitelist certain passwords, like "admin", would be very useful here.  I'm tempted to disable this feature during local development, but I know I will forget to turn it back on later.